# Почему при перевороте массива длину массива нужно делить на 2?

Tags: java, массивы

Почему в цикле `for` длину массива нужно обязательно делить на `2`? По идее от таких выкрутасов массив перевернётся не полностью. Однако в реальности всё работает.

Код:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++) {
        byte tmp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[buffer.length - i - 1];
        array[buffer.length - i - 1] = tmp;
    }
```

Не логичнее было бы ограничить цикл просто длиной массива?

Comment: Каждый обмен изменяет положение 2 элементов. Всего элементов array.length. Чтобы каждый поменял место один раз, нужно array.length/2 обменов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что в одной итерации меняются два элемента - первый с последним. Потом второй с предпоследним и т.д. от концов к середине. В середине прекращаем, т.к. обе половины изменены.

А если на два не делить, то массив не изменится :)

Answer (score 5):

Потому что в цикле меняется элемент из первой **половины** массива с зеркально расположенным элементом из второй **половины**

При цикле до конца обмены пар будут происходить дважды, и в результате массив останется в первоначальном состоянии.

Разве этого нельзя увидеть, прогнав простой тест?